# How to compute a simple cross-tabulation of two (or more) factor?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to cross two pandas tables in way like that:

Table 1

```
+-----+-----+
| id  |label|
+-----+-----+
| 1   |  2  |
| 2   |  0  |
| 3   |  1  |
+-----+-----+
```

Table 2:

```
+-----+-----+
| id  |label|
+-----+-----+
| 1   |  1  |
| 2   |  1  |
| 3   |  0  |
+-----+-----+
```

Goal:

Table 3: sum labels crossing tables

```
+-----+---+---+---+
|     |1  |2  |3  |
+-----+---+---+---+
| 1   | 3 | 3 | 2 | 
| 2   | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3   | 2 | 2 | 1 |
+-----+---+---+---+
```

code:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [2, 0, 1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [1, 1, 0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: CVers: I don't believe this question should be closed so hastily. It provides input, expected output, and reproducible code examples, and is much better than what we're normally used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a broadcasted addition of the two vectors -

```
v = df1.label[:, None] + df2.label.values
```

Or, using `np.add.outer` to automatically broadcast addition for you -

```
v = np.add.outer(df1.label, df2.label)
```

Finally, convert the result to a `DataFrame` -

```
pd.DataFrame(v, index=df1.id, columns=df2.id)

id  1  2  3
id         
1   3  3  2
2   1  1  0
3   2  2  1
```

---

For a second header, construct a `MultiIndex` -

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['header'], df2.id])
pd.DataFrame(v, index=df1.id, columns=idx)

   header      
        1  2  3
id             
1       3  3  2
2       1  1  0
3       2  2  1
```

Comment: @Thaise You're welcome. You can also upvote the answer if it was helpful. Cheers.

Comment: How to add a header?

Comment: @Thaise Can you please rephrase? What kind of header? Where should it go?

Comment: Ah, ok! I meant : id header above result table.

Comment: plus1 for the outer add